# Expo Dev tools not showing in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to React Native and I'm just starting to learn about it but I noticed from different tutorials that expo has a dev tool that open in web browser which don't work for me.

I'm using expo-cli: version 6.0.2 and 46.0.7.

What should I do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you open developer menu is a bit different depending on where you're running the Expo Go app:

- iOS Device: Shake the device a little bit, or touch 3 fingers to the screen.
- iOS Simulator: Hit `Ctrl + Cmd ⌘ + Z` on a Mac in the emulator to simulate the shake gesture, or press `Cmd ⌘ + D`.
- Android Device: Shake the device vertically a little bit, or run `adb shell input keyevent 82` in your terminal window if your device is connected via USB.
- Android Emulator: Either hit `Cmd ⌘ + M` or `Ctrl + M` or run `adb shell input keyevent 82` in your terminal window.

Check the [expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/debugging/#developer-menu)...

Comment: Thank you for the fast response I really didn't know about the shake option It's really useful but what I'm referring to is this page.

https://cdn-clekk.nitrocdn.com/tkvYXMZryjYrSVhxKeFTeXElceKUYHeV/assets/static/optimized/rev-5ea28ac/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/expo-developer-tool_1-min.png

Comment: from the developer menu you can toggle debugger..

Comment: The web ui has been removed... ref: https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

Comment: ahh Thank Sayeed for the resource.